# sig is abstract, but alloy analyzer make an instance of it

Tags: alloy

I have the following very simple model in Alloy:

```
abstract sig Object {}
pred show(){}
run show for 5
```

when I execute this model, Why alloy analyzer still makes an instance of **Object** while it is defined to be abstract!

Answer (score 7):

An abstract signature can contain atoms so long as it has no subsignatures. This is designed to allow you to build and animate a model incrementally, so you can mark a signature as abstract with the expectation that subsignatures will be introduced later.